# Proving that a unicellular operator is necessarily irreducible?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, linear-transformations

I would like to prove that a unicellular operator must be irreducible.

Here we define $A$ as being a unicellular operator if it is both non-derogatory (minimum annihilating polynomial is equal to characteristic polynomial) and is monosemic (has just one eigen value $\lambda$).

Likewise we say $A$ is irreducible if there is no non-trivial reducing subspace relative to $A$, eg. There is no non-trivial subspace $M$ such that both $M$ and $\bar{M}$ are invariant under $A$.

I attempted several different routes to arrive at some kind of contradiction but haven't gotten anywhere and feel like I've made no progress.

For example I thought that maybe assuming otherwise would lead to a contradiction of  $\text{dim } Ker(A-\lambda I) = 1$ which is a requirement for $A$ to be non-derogatory, but have no idea how to get there from just assuming there is a non-trivial reducing subspace.

Comment: What is $\bar M$? From context it seems it would be some kind of complementary subspace.  If an orthogonal complement in an inner product space then $M^\perp$ might be clearer.  If just an arbitrary complementary subspace, such that your vector space is $M+\bar M$ and $M\cap \bar M =\{0\}$, this could be stated.  It could also be stated explicitly what sort of space (finite dimensional vector space? f.d. inner product space?  over which field?) $A$ is an operator on.

Comment: Sorry, in the text is refers to it as a compliment so I assumed it meant $E=M + \bar{M}$ and $M \cap \bar{M} = 0$. It is also a finite dimensional vectorspace. Apologies for leaving this out.

Comment: Yeah sorry, getting confused with new notation, the "compliment" part made me think of union, the book does indeed use $+$. Fixed my comment.

Comment: Sounds good.  And it is a vector space over what field?  The unique eigenvalue is in that field, and there are no others even in extension fields?   This seemed a reasonable assumption to me, made in the answer, and is the only part assumed still not necessarily justified from the information given.

Comment: The book is just on linear spaces if that answers the question about fields? Sorry, my background is not analysis so this is all new to me. If I could just clarify: Does the notation $U+V$ mean all elements $x$ that can be expressed as $x=u+v$, $u \in U$, $v \in V$ in this context? And the phrase "direct sum" mean that each $x$ has a unique $u$ and $v$?

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer the question, but from context I think there's enough info to realize the field must not be important.  If the book mentioned no qualifiers about where the eigenvalue lies, then the assumptions mentioned above are reasonable.  Yes $U+V$ is the set of all vectors of that form, and the representation is unique when $U\cap V=0$, in which case it is considered an "internal" direct sum.  The "external" direct sum is where you take two vector spaces and define componentwise operations on their cartesian product.

Comment: The same terminology is used because $x = u+v \mapsto (u,v)$ gives an isomorphism from $U+V$ to the external direct sum of $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is your vector space and it has a decomposition $V=V_1+V_2$ with $V_1$ and $V_2$ subspaces such that $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$, and such that both $V_1$ and $V_2$ are invariant for $A$, then the restrictions of $A$ to each subspace define operators $A_1:V_1\to V_1$, $A_2:V_2\to V_2$.

If the dimension of $V$ is $n$ you have $(A-\lambda I)^n=0$ but $(A-\lambda I)^{n-1}\neq 0$.   The first equation implies $(A_j-\lambda I)^n=0$ for $j=1,2$, which in turn implies that $(A_j-\lambda I)^{\dim(V_j)}=0$ for $j=1,2$.  This in turn implies that $(A-\lambda I)^{\max\{\dim(V_1),\dim(V_2)\}}=0$.  Because $(A-\lambda I)^{n-1}\neq 0$, this implies that $V_1=V$ and $V_2=\{0\}$ or vice versa.